# FileOutputStream causes an exception when trying to FileOutputStream( externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() );

Tags: android, sd-card

I am trying to write a simple test method to copy a file from the Asset folder  to the sd card.  When I try to open a file on the sd card it crashes.

code

```
        try {
              // POpne file from asset
               AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
               InputStream inputStream;
               inputStream = assetManager.open("test");

               // open output folder
               File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                       // CRASHES HERE
               out = new FileOutputStream(  externalStorage.getAbsolutePath()  );
               int c;

            while ((c =  inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } catch( Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your app?

Comment: Nop, easy fix!, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to mention File Access permission in AndroidManifest.xml, just write following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hi,No I forgot, got it to worck now, thank you for your help :)